# Chrome Native messaging in Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to implement a native messaging with chrome app in Python but without using Tkinter (used in the [official example])[1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host/native-messaging-example-host)

So essentialy my question is: is it possible to connect the chrome js app to a python script running in a terminal? How?

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would it be different from the example? Tkinter is just used there to show the responses.

Comment: it doesn't start (from the app menu when you hit connect it starts the tkinter app, without tkinter it doesn't start the terminal running the script, it shows nothing) + i don't know how to implement a listen feature in a script without using tkinter, wile 1?